How to spawn a robot model precisely on top of a plane?
In Gazebo Harmonic, I want to spawn a robot model on top of a plane during the simulation execution.
The intent is to use gz::sim:SdfEntityCreator.CreateEntities to spawn a robot model from an SDF/URDF string specified by the user. This model should be spawned exactly on top of a plane. The processing happens in a server plugin.
Consider that the plane is orthogonal to the Z axis, and is placed in z=0. Also consider that the robot SDF/URDF doesn't specify any Pose for the robot. It's the plugin's responsibility to add a gz::sim::components::Pose component to the robot's entity once it's created.
My definition of "exactly on top of the plane" means that the robot model informed by the user has it's axis-aligned bounding box "touching" the plane.
Here's the challenge I'm facing:
Let's say the robot's model bounding box has height=10. For it to be place exactly on top of the plane at z=0, the plugin must specify z=10/2=5 for the Pose component. If the Pose was set to 0, the robot would essentially be "cut in half" by the plane. This means that the value required for the pose depends on the robot model (which is not known beforehand).
I haven't found a way to infer or calculate the model's height right after the robot's entity is created.
The only way I could find was to add a gz::sim::components::AxisAlignedBox to the robot's model and let one update cycle pass. During the next update, the physics engine will have calculated the bounding box's dimensions for all models, and I would be able to reassign the robot's pose based on that. This has the downside that the robot has to be spawned in an arbitrary location, run for an update loop, and then be teleported to the desired location.
A possible workaround is to place the robot in a z assumed to be bigger than half of the model's height and let it fall down.
Is there a way to achieve the same behavior without relying on these not-so-ideal approaches?
related: Query the dimensions of a model
